# Trying this code to parse JSON data from URL into html

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I've written this code (it might be just a little bit messy). I'm trying to read JSON data from a URL and display it in html (in a simple for now, a nicer one better)

This is what I have. It's not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var jsonApi = "http://10.0.0.2/~nrgtar/test.php?query=64"
 $.getJSON(jsonApi, function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in jsonApi.results) {
            output+="<li>" + data.results[i].name + " " + data.results[i].lastname + "--" + data.results[i].address+"</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

An example JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "lastname":"Smith",
            "address":"4 main street"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: _'It's not working'_ is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: `for (var i in data.results)`

Comment: Thanks :) I'll change it. I mean, trying to run the html file, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<?php

$url = "http://10.0.0.2/~nrgstar/test.php?query=4";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['results'] as $item) {
print "name " . $item['name'] . " last name " . $item['lastname'] . " address " . $item['address'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Nothing suggests the asker is using PHP, so this answer is not a helpful response.

Comment: Except the answer is by given by the person who asked the question, plus php is a tag.

Comment: Alright. If the question is improved (note it's at -5) it might make it clearer that the problem is one in a PHP script, not in, say, JavaScript. If the problem is in your PHP, a nonworking PHP script is suspiciously absent from the question.